# Drawbacks of having a large Branching factor in a B-tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory, b-tree, red-black-tree

In this [paper](https://deepai.org/publication/belga-b-trees) by Demain, et al: a new data structure is proposed where a tree of B-trees is implemented to achieve dynamic optimality. In the entire paper, it is assumed that the B = (logN)^O(1).

Similar to [Tango trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango_tree), here also preferred paths are created using the previously accessed nodes. These preferred paths are stored as auxiliary b-trees, and a tree of these auxiliary trees is created. This dynamic tree is called Belga-B tree.

When we are searching for an access sequence, we can access a node of the b-tree and the higher the branching factor is, lesser nodes need to be accessed to search for a key. But the authors have put a limit on B = (logN)^O(1).

Also, they have mentioned that when B = (logN)^O(1), then

1 + log<sub>B</sub>log(N) = O(log<sub>B</sub>log(N) )

Why is this condition necessary for the algorithm to work?

I fail to understand the significance of this. We know that the more the branching factor is, less would be the height of the tree and hence less time of access. Why is there a restriction on the value of B?

Even when the algorithm is explained, nowhere have they used the fact that B is polynomial in logN.

Comment: You should probably consider including more background information.

Comment: I have added some more information.